# BASH String concatenation adds "^M" character

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have the following script that reads through a file line by line

```
_PATH=$(pwd)
LOCATION_PATH="$_PATH/inventory.sh"
LETTER="l"
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo $line >> file2.test
    CALL="${LOCATION_PATH} ${line} ${LETTER} 1234"
    echo $CALL >> file.test
    echo =========
    RESULT=$($CALL)
    #echo $RESULT
done < "$1"
```

But while the input file for each line has NO `^M` (carriage return) character in it, the output of the file.test file has them as follows:

> /.../inventory.sh 00000e99-bce9-11e4-8418-06e8ce2b06d8^M l 1234
>   /.../inventory.sh 0001688b-bce7-11e4-8418-06e8ce2b06d8^M l 1234

The output to file2.test alos has no `^M` character.

I have tried substituting as follows:

```
SP=" "
LE="l"
...    
    CALL="${LOCATION_PATH}${SP}${line}${SP}${LE}${SP}1234"
```

To no avail.

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020883/unix-script-appends-m-at-end-of-each-line). You should be adding a command `dos2unix` to convert the file into an Unix readable file.

Comment: How do you know the input file doesn't have CRs? Your editor may hide it. See the output of `sed -n l filename` to make invisible characters visible.

Comment: @Philippos - well I am capable of checking that file.test has these characters, I used the same technique to check the input files

Comment: (1) You are probably wrong about ***both*** the input and the `file2.test` output file.  Unless you present evidence that you have checked correctly, I’m going to assume that they all have CRs. (2) You should probably use more quotes.

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon CRs inside a line a typically displayed `^M`, while at the end of the line they are typically hidden. So please verify your assumption with the given `sed` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

^M is a sign that you created the input data providing the ${line} variable in Windows, for that's an end-of-line character in Windows.  If you transfer a file edited in Windows to Linux, you need to run the "dos2unix" command on it before using it in Unix/Linux.

To see whether this is the case, you can run the "od -Xc" command on the input file to hexdump it -- and then to look for carriage-return/line-feed characters instead of newlines.  If you see characters like \r\l rather than \n then you've found the culprit.

Comment: Thank you. I needed to do a `| tr '\r' ' '` on the line and that removed it

Comment: That replaced it with a space, to be exact. So finally you believe that there were CRs in your input?

Comment: Mr. Balsdon,  glad you solved your problem.  "tr" is definitely a solution to use in a streaming environment.  The "dos2unix" solution would be performed against the entire file prior to moving it through the pipeline.